# Ubuntu 18.04: GUI not starting after fresh install

Tags: boot, gui, radeon

I have set up a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation but can't get the GUI to start. I tried several suggested solutions on the internet but none have worked.

I use a Acer A515-44G with a AMD Radeon RX 640 graphics card and a AMD Ryzen™ 7 4700U CPU.

After booting for the first time, the screen sort of freezes and the cursor starts flickering. I can access the TTY but it is rather useless. The flickering causes keystrokes to only by recognized sporadically, so I can not enter my password correctly since input characters are hidden. [The screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW7Ie.jpg) displays

```
Failed to start User Manager for UID 121
```

I can access the GUI with "nomodeset" in GRUB commandline but that causes my fan to spin pretty fast (I guess that is because the CPU has to do all the screen drawing in nomodeset mode and consequently gets pretty hot, but correct me on that, I am no expert).
In GUI I then switched from gdm3 to lightdm.

Using lightdm fixes the flickering problem, so I was now able to access a TTY. According to several suggestions on the internet I then tried running startx. I do not know what I should have expected from that, but it did not work. [Logfile contents are here.](https://pastebin.com/HWJvURLi)

I did some research on that "Please specify busIDs" part, but the internet was not very helpful with that. I am also not sure which other log files I should read so that they can help me find a solution, or at least the problem's cause.

I would really appreciate any thoughts on this topic.

Edit: Sorry I forgot to mention, the same thing originally happened on Ubuntu 20.04. I downgraded to 18.04 since I had that one working on another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what caused this issue, but I fixed it by following some steps from [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/AMD/radeon/). I had originally switched to `lightdm` but I had to switch back to `gdm3` using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` for the following to work.

First I reinstalled xserver-xorg-video-ati. The package was already installed, but I ran the command anyways.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati --reinstall
```

Then I had to create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and edit as as follows:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "radeon"
EndSection
```

Then after restarting the GUI was started.